# How to write a file in Windows driver folder?

Tags: windows-8.1

I am writing a file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and want an access to write in a file but I am not getting it. I have tried to allow it for the admin but still it is not allowed.

How can I get write access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the application as admin (right click and select "Run as administrator"). By default all applications run in a limited mode due to UAC in Windows since Vista. In with limited rights they can't write into system folders.